# Pegar valor da TAG "<link>" de HTML externo

Tags: php, html

Preciso pegar o valor (ou os valores, caso tenha mais de uma) da TAG `<link>` de um HTML  de outro site.

#### Tentativa:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/teste/';
$content = trim(file_get_contents($url));
preg_match("/<link(.*?)>/i",$content,$return); 
var_dump($return);
```

#### Retorno:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/teste/icon.png">' (length=77)
  1 => string ' rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/teste/icon.png"' (length=71)
```

---

Não sei se deixei bem claro, mas gostaria que retornasse o seguinte:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'rel' => string 'shortcut icon' (length=13)
      'href' => string 'http://localhost/teste/icon.png' (length=31)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade, a **expressão regular** (uma vez que trabalhar com HTML deve ser feito com a DOM) mais abrangente e, consequentemente, mais adequada seria:

```
/<link.*?href="(.*?)".*?>/i
```

Haja vista que:

- Dada a classificação do *stack* como PHP e demonstração de uso com [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match), o modificador **g** não existe dentre os suportados pelos [Modificadores PCRE](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) disponíveis.
- De acordo com as especificações HTML e XHTML a tag <link> não tem valor, apenas atributos, diferenciando-se, principalmente, pelo encerramento da tag.
- Deve-se considerar que nem sempre o atributo **href** desejado terá seu valor numa mesma posição, nem mesmo caso tenha sido você a escrever o HTML. Por isso a consideração de se haver qualquer coisa antes e depois do atributo.

Quanto a utilização, para se capturar todos os valores, basta que use [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all).

[EDIT]

Conforme apontado pelo @Sergio, com a edição do *stack* inicial a solução apresentada acima não mais se aplica, no entanto, a explicação aqui contida é de grande valia e só por isso permance.

Estarei removendo, no entanto, o que for supérfluo. Conteúdo que possivelmente estará disponível nas revisões dessa resposta (assumindo que seja um recurso global).

Peço que leia com muta atenção e entenda como tudo fica mais complicado quando se tenta parafusar usando um martelo:

1. Primeiro mudamos a Expressão Regular para encontrarmos todos os atributos.
2. Como o PHP não captura "grupos de grupos" automaticamente, ou seja, você define algo a ser capturado e ele captura tantas vezes quantas ocorrências desse padrão existirem, é preciso separar cada par chave=valor.

   Com PHP se faz muito de muitas formas e uma alternativa viável seria remover os espaços entre os pares chave=valor e usar [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/parse_str). Mas como para isso precisaríamos de uma ER, uma vez que um [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/str_replace) simples bagunçaria, por exemplo, o **rel**, façamos tudo por ER.
3. Temos de iterar o array produzido por [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all), isso é inevitável, mas como estarei aplicando uma mesma rotina, sobre cada elemento do array, mapeando seus dados em outra coisa, prefiro usar [array_map()](http://www.php.net/array_map):
4. [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/preg_split) faz o serviço dela, mas mesmo ela entregando um array, este não está no formato que você precisa, tendo os atributos como índice. Podemos contornar com [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/array_chunk):
5. Mas [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/array_chunk) produz N arrays dentro de outro que já tinhamos, que por sua vez está dentro de outro. OMFG! Eu não quero iterar tudo isso! Nesse caso, um truque sensacional é transpor a matriz e, para isso, provavelmente a resposta prática mais bem votada que eu já vi vêm [desse stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php) no SO em inglês.

Quando se transpõe essa matriz, ela fica desse jeito:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'rel' (length=3)
      1 => string 'href' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'shortcut icon' (length=13)
      1 => string 'http://localhost/teste/icon1.png' (length=32)
```

Estrutura essa que um [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/array_combine) consegue lidar facilmente:

O código completo pode ser copiado e visualizado em execução através [desse link](http://ideone.com/JonV4J).

Answer (score 8):

Tente buscar o dado dentro de um HTML navegando pelo DOM, e não usando expressões regulares. Pode acontecer de, hipoteticamente, haver um `link` dentro de outro `link` e por conta disso, sua expressão falhar.

Existe uma postagem relativamente antiga –mas bastante conhecida– sobre o porquê de não se usar expressões regulares para interpretar um HTML. Basicamente, HTML não é uma linguagem regular e, por definição, não poderia ser interpretada por uma expressão regular.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Isso, é claro, se estivermos falando de uma situação em que você pode navegar pelo DOM do HTML (como você está usando PHP, é válido).

Minha solução, então, segue a seguinte:

```
<?php
$html = trim(file_get_contents('http://localhost/teste/'));
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    print_r($link->getAttributes());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você poderia usar a classe [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm) tem uma boa documentação

Answer (score 3):

Eu recomendo usar o [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm), ele é ótimo e muito fácil de usar, eu uso em vários scripts para analisar HTML de outros sites.

Muito boa a resposta do Bruno Augusto, apenas quero complementar a resposta dele e dar mais uns detalhes que acho que são importantes serem observados e levados em conta. Quando eu preciso analisar conteúdo HTML e uso expressão regular para isso, eu procuro fazer um código mais completo pois HTML é muito irregular, os atributos não tem ordem definida, e podem ter códigos com quebras de linhas, sugiro que use uma expressão regular mais "completa", no seu caso eu usaria esta expressão regular:

```
/<link.*?href=\"([^\"]*?)\".*?\/?>/si
```

Basicamente as melhorias são 2 substituições:

1 - de `(.*?)` por `([^\"]*?)` pois é o certo a se fazer, pois não existem caracteres `"` se o delimitador do atributo também é `"`, o mesmo vale se fosse o caractere `'`.

2 - de `>` por `\/?>` pois pode haver ou não o caractere `/` antes do caractere `<`.

3 - de `/i` por `/si` pois podem haver quebras de linhas entre os atributos, valores, etc... nem sempre as tags HTML nos sites estão totalmente inline, podem estar um pedaço  numa linha e outro pedaço na outra linha.

Se você usar a expressão regular original sugerida pelo **Bruno Augusto**, ela pode não encontrar determinados códigos da tag LINK se eles estiverem com quebras de linhas ou se tiverem o carectere `/` (barra, que representa a tag de fechamento), exemplo:

```
$string = <<<EOF
<link
rel="shortcut icon"
href="http://localhost/teste/icon.png"
>
EOF;

if ( preg_match_all( '/<link.*?href="(.*?)".*?>/i', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
    var_dump( $matches );
    die();
} else {
    echo 'Nenhuma tag encontrada.';
    /* Esta parte será executada pois não serão encontrados tags, devido as quebras de linhas e adicionalmente também há a presença do caractere "/" (barra) do fechamento da tag LINK */
}
```

Agora usando o mesmo código do exemplo com a expressão regular mais completa sugerida por mim, vão ser obtidos os resultados com sucesso:

```
$string = <<<EOF
<link
rel="shortcut icon"
href="http://localhost/teste/icon.png"
>
EOF;

if ( preg_match_all( '/<link.*?href=\"([^\"]*?)\".*?\/?>/si', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
    /* Tags encontradas com sucesso */
    var_dump( $matches );
    die();
}
```